# How to get a constructor as a function from the (G)ADT argument in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, gadt

How to get a constructor as a function from the (G)ADT argument in Haskell?
Is it possible to do something like this?

```
data  Ex1 =  C1 Int | C2 Int -- | ..... 
           | C3

fun :: Ex1 -> Ex1
fun C3    = C3
fun (c i) = c $ i^2
```

It is not appropriate for me to.

```
fun (C1 i) = C1 $ i^2
fun (C2 i) = C2 $ i^2
```

Comment: Why is matching on the constructors 'not appropriate'?

Comment: Because a lot constructors. I do not want to duplicate the big code. In fact. data AST = Imm Int | Arg Int | Add AST AST | Sub AST AST | Mul AST AST | Div AST AST ......

Comment: Big data types are something of a code smell. It might be worth trying to simplify the design of your AST.

Comment: To @BenjaminHodgson's point, you can always do something like `data AST = ... | BinOp BinOpType AST AST` with `data BinOpType = Add | Sub | Mul | Div`.

Answer (score 6):

If you are ok with changing the type of `Ex1` then:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFunctor #-}

data  Ex1 a =  C1 a | C2 a
            | C3 deriving (Show, Functor)

fun :: Ex1 Int -> Ex1 Int
fun y = fmap (\x -> x^2) y
```

Demo in `ghci`:

```
λ> fun $ C1 3
C1 9
λ> fun $ C2 3
C2 9
λ> fun C3
C3
```

Comment: Thank U. But I'm too simplified real task. In fact. 
 data AST   = Imm Int
           | Arg Int
           | Add AST AST
           | Sub AST AST
           | Mul AST AST
           | Div AST AST
 
reduce:: (Int->Int->Int) -> AST -> AST
reduce f (t a b) = go a b 
    where go (Imm a) (Imm b) = Imm $ f a b
               go a b = t a b

Comment: This will still work for your use case with `data AST a = Imm a | Arg Int | Add (AST a) (AST a) | ...`. Then you just need an extra function for `Arg`, assuming that `Imm` is the constructor for values in your expression language and that `Arg` is something else. `Arg a` might work as well, depending on what the constructors represent.